# Not able to max out RAM in Dell inspiron 5370

Tags: laptop, memory, dell-inspiron

The laptop came with a single DDR4 RAM (2400 MHz)module of 8 GB installed in slot 1. The other slot was empty. Lets call these slots S1 and S2 respectively.

I bought two identical 2400 MHz DDR4 modules of 16 GB each to get the max of 32 GB as mentioned in its [user-guide](https://images-eu.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/A1MTV2MKGSS.pdf).

Lets call each new SO-DIMMs M1 and M2. Lets call the old RAM module M0

Putting both M1 and M2 in the laptop didn't work. The power LED blinked red and white. The following table summarizes my issue.

```
S1 | S2 | Works?
---|----|-------
M1 | M2 | NO (LED blinking, No display)
M2 | M1 | NO (LED blinking, No display)
M1 |    | YES
M2 |    | YES
M0 |    | YES (original configuration)
M1 | M0 | YES
M2 | M0 | YES
```

Other combinations not yet tried.
Thus, I am not able to get both new modules to work simultaneously. Each one works individually and also alongside the original module.

Would appreciate any clues on the issue.

Comment: First thing: Update the BIOS, as you did not mention this, I assume you did not check that.

Comment: @davidbaumann I have not done this. Is this necessary? I don't want to risk bricking the laptop

Comment: I never bricked a laptop running a BIOS update. But I have fixed problem by updating